# Python: Reiterating through subprocess.call command

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I have the following code to re-iterate through a IP address list to find the SNMP string:

**INPUT:**

```
import os
import subprocess
ip_list = ['10.10.10.10','10.10.10.11']
snmp = "snmpget -v1 -c public "

for x in ip_list:
     command = os.system(str(snmp + x))
```

**OUTPUT:** ... = STRING: "11/15/2017"

This code works fine, but I need to replace os.system with subprocess.call as os.system is very limited and can not be stored in a variable.

I tried to plug in subprocess.call in but i keep getting the error:

```
results = subprocess.call(os.system(str(snmp + r + static_oid + z)), shell=True)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you show the subprocess code you've used? also show the value/type of the variables. ATM it's unanswerable.

Comment: woops, sorry. updated with variable examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

erm, you're *chaining* `os.system` call with `subprocess.call` call. This is completely wrong. And the cryptic message root cause is that you're passing the return code of `os.system` which is an integer, when `subprocess.call` tries to iterate on the argument.

Switching to `subprocess` is a great idea because `os.system` is deprecated and is prone to security issues. That is, if you consider dropping `shell=True`.

And to drop `shell=True`, you have to pass a *list* of arguments, not composing your arg string yourself.

My proposal:

```
import os
import subprocess
ip_list = ['10.10.10.10','10.10.10.11']
snmp = ["snmpget","-v1","-c","public"]   # list of arguments

outputs = []
for x in ip_list:
     cp = subprocess.run(snmp + [x],check=False)
     outputs.append(cp.stdout.decode())
```

this runs your command in a safe, simple way, gets the output and puts each output line in a list of strings (trying to assign the output didn't work either with `call` or `os.system` since it returns the *exit code*, not the program output. 
Since your command can return a nonzero return code you cannot use [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) but you can use [`run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is what you need (but you need python 3.5, else you'll have to use a `Popen` solution, described here: [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)):

```
 p = subprocess.Popen(snmp + [x])
 result = p.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. When i tried snmp + [x], i am getting the TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects. any ideas how i can string up snmp and variable x?

Comment: that's because you didn't change `snmp` to list. Check my answer again

Comment: i see, my bad. Updated snmp variable to: snmp = ["snmpget -v1 -c public "] as it is one argument but now i get this error. 

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: check my answer _again_. Paste from here. you're just putting your string in a list, which isn't correct.

Comment: hmm, i get the error message: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['snmpget', '-v1', '-c', 'public', '10.10.10.10']' returned non-zero exit status 1

again thanks for the support!

Comment: you have to use `run` which doesn't crash when returncode is not 0, check my edit

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction! i had to use Popen as i am not running version 3.5. for those who may need it in the future, i used: p = subprocess.Popen(snmp + [x]) result = p.communicate()[0] print result

Answer (score -2):

import os
import subprocess
ip_list = ['10.10.10.10','10.10.10.11']
snmp = ["snmpget","-v1","-c","public"]   # list of arguments

outputs = []
for x in ip_list:
     cp = subprocess.run(snmp + [x],check=False)
     outputs.append(cp.stdout.decode())